# Htaccess редирект всех поддоменов кроме www

Tags: .htaccess

Я написал .htaccess который перенаправляет все поддомены в директорию /sub/ сейчас вышла такая проблема:

если я ввожу **www.site.ru** он перенаправляет в директорию /sub/ он не должен www переанправлять как мне это исправить ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www).+)\.site\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```